# Noncapturing along with capturing match

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to capture the subdomain from huge lists of domain names.  For example I want to capture "funstuff" from "funstuff.mysite.com".  I do not want to capture, ".mysite.com" in the match. These occurances are in a sea of text so I can not depend on them being at the start of a line. I know the subdomain will not include any special characters or numbers.  So what I have is:

```
[a-z]{2,10}(?=\.mysite\.com)
```

The problem is this will work only if the subdomain is NOT preceded by a number or special character.  For example, "asdfbasdasdfdfunstuff.mysite.com" will return "fdfunstuff" but "asdfasf23/funstuff.mysite.com" won't make a match.

I can not depend on there being a special character before the subdomain, like a "/" as in "http://funstuff.mysite.com" so that can not be used as part of the condition.

It is ok if the capture gets erroneous text before the subdomain, although  99% of the time it will be preceded with something other that a lowercase letter.  I have tried,

```
(?<=[^a-z])[a-z]{2,10}(?=\.mysite\.com)
```

but for some reason this does not capture text is a situation like:

```
afb"asdfunstuff.mysite.com
```

Where the quotation mark prevents a match for `[a-z]{2-20}`.  Basically what I would want to do in that case would be to capture asdfunstuff.mysite.com.  How can this be accomplished?

Comment: Your first regex is capable of matching the example where it's not matching for you. What method are you calling to do the regex evaluation?

Comment: sounds like you want `\b` aka "word boundary" at the beginning, so e.g. `\b([a-z]{2,10})\.mysite\.com`. Note I've escaped the dots here, and the capture group is only around the "subdomain" part.

Comment: Jeremy... that was it! Thanks. I hadn't heard of \b function before.  Thanks for catching my lack of escape characters as well.  I've edited the post to correctly reflect it.

Comment: Looks like a few people have found this useful, so I might write it up as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you've got two problems to solve: first, you want to match ".mysite.com" but not capture it; second, you want to grab up to 10 alphabetic characters in the "subdomain" position.

**First problem** can be solved by using a capturing group. The regex

```
([a-z]{2,10})\.mysite\.com
```

will capture somewhere between 2 and 10 characters, and the returned `match` object will expose that in one of its properties (depends on the language). C# returns a collection of [`Match`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.match.aspx) objects, so it'll be the only item.

**Second problem** can be solved by using the word-boundary character `\b`. [In .NET, this matches where an alphanumeric (i.e. `\w`) is next to a non-alphanumeric (`\W`).](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#atomic_zerowidth_assertions) Other languages (e.g. ECMAScript / Javascript) work simliarly.

So, I suggest the following regex to solve your problem:

```
\b([a-z]{2,10})\.mysite\.com
```

Note that numbers are legal in subdomain names, too, so the following might be generally correct (though perhaps not in your specific case):

```
\b(\w{2,10})\.mysite\.com
```

where the "word character" `\w` is equivalent to `[a-zA-Z_0-9]` in .NET's ECMAScript-compliant mode. ([Further reading.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#WordCharacter))